# How to change background color repeatedly on Android?

Tags: android, background-color

I have a countdown timer that onFinished I want to have the screen change colors repeatedly.

I'm trying:

```
public void onFinish() {
findViewById(R.id.screenid).setTag("BLACK");
_timer2=new Timer();
_timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(Flashscreen, 0,1700);}



TimerTask Flashscreen = new TimerTask()
{
    public void run() {

        if ( findViewById(R.id.screenid).getTag()=="BLACK" )
        {
            findViewById(R.id.screenid).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            findViewById(R.id.screenid).setTag("BLUE");
            return;
        }
        if (findViewById(R.id.screenid).getTag()=="BLUE")
        {
            findViewById(R.id.screenid).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            findViewById(R.id.screenid).setTag("BLACK");
            return;

        }
                }};
```

But it will only change the color to blue once. What's happening wrong?

Comment: Debug your code and make sure that the 2nd time, the tag has changed to **BLUE** and it's not still **BLACK**

Comment: You should also create a reference for your view instead of calling findViewById() several times. That is a costly method

Comment: @Dave: Firstly `getTag()` returns an `Object` which you need to cast to a `String`. Secondly don't use `==` for comparing reference types. The answer from Stephan van den Heuvel should work - use `.equals(...)` when comparing `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try putting both changing of color to run on uithread.
Something like below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override  
    public void run() {
        findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setTag("BLACK");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it checking for object equality and not string content equality?

Try changing

```
( findViewById(R.id.screenid).getTag()=="BLACK" )
```

To

```
(((String)findViewById(R.id.screenid).getTag()).equals("BLACK"))
```

And likewise for the check for "BLUE"

Basically, '==' checks to see if the reference is the same, as in they are both pointing to the same object. 'equals' actually checks to see if the *content* of the strings are equal.

Comment: Just tried that but it still only goes to the blue screen first.

Comment: I should have done that in the first place and with nandeesh's answer I bet this also made it work. Thanks.